# aws batch out of memory error even though increased memory to 100Gb

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch

I am running a aws batch job, but it is failing because of Out of Memory error. I have tried to run the job, by incrementally increasing both memory and vcpus, starting from 8vcpus, 80000Mb, I have gone upto 64vcpus and 100000Mb, but still the batch job failed with OOM error.
One more thing, I would like to mention is that in my compute environment, I have specified m5.4xlarge and in the aws documentations I can see it goes uptil 16vcpus and 64gb.
My question is, could this be the cause of OOM error, i.e. asking for more memory than what is being possible in compute environment?

Comment: Yeah you should not be asking for more than is available on an instance (if you are restricting instances) in the job definition [resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/APIReference/API_ResourceRequirement.html). I'm surprised it ran at all since Batch treats memory as a hard limit and would want to launch instances to support your specification, and the m5.4xl does not meet your requirements